# "Unable to find the report in the manifest resources" .NET 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports

I know this question have been asked before. But i have tried the answers in the other questions without any luck. I have removed the Namespacing from the .rpt file reference and also set the build action of the file to be Embedded Resource but nothing helps i still get the same error. The error occurs here:

```
  public override string FullResourceName {
            get {
                return "RptManifest3.rpt";
            } <--------
            set {
                // Do nothing
            }
        }
```

When the code reaches the arrow i get the error. Anybody who can help with this ?

Comment: Please see this

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6367624/unable-to-find-the-report-in-the-manifest-resources/29602674#29602674][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6367624/unable-to-find-the-report-in-the-manifest-resources/29602674#29602674

Answer (score -1):

Finally i could solve the problem
just go to the references and choose all the 'dll's starts with 'crystalldesicion' there.
after you choose them all, find the 'Copy Local' property in properties table, now change its value to 'true'.
build the project and save it all.
now its ready to action